# SingleObserver onSubscribe Funcation always return null in Android Retrofi

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I have a problem with retrofit and rxjava
my code below :

```java
 @GET(ApiAddress.LANGUAGE_ALL)
 Single<Response<Language>> languageAll();
```

and implements it :

```java
    apiRepository.languageAll().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new SubscribeWithView<Response<Language>>(view) {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Response<Language> response) {
                            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                                view.setLanguage(response.getData().getResults());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            super.onError(e);
                        }
                    });
```

and my `SubscribeWithView` below:

```java
public abstract class SubscribeWithView<T> implements SingleObserver<T> {


    private WeakReference<RootView> rootView;

    public SubscribeWithView(RootView rootView) {
        this.rootView = new WeakReference<>(rootView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        if (rootView.get() != null)
            rootView.get().addDisposable(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (rootView.get() != null)
            rootView.get().onError(e);
    }
}
```

why `onSubscribe(Disposable d)` : `d` always `null` ???

Comment: In `onSubscribe(Disposable d)`, `d` is never `null`, but `d.toString()` could get printed as `"null"`.

Comment: @akarnokd , Unfortunately, the value of the null is debug

Comment: Place a `.doOnSubscribe(d -> System.out.println(d == null))` before `subscribe(` and tell me what it prints.

Comment: @akarnokd  , i am add below code but alwayse log "false"

.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
                    Override
                    public void accept(Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
                        if (disposable == null)
                            Log.e("_xxx_", "true");
                        else Log.e("_###_", "false");
                    }
                })
                .subscribe()

Comment: That means `d` is not null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get a null value error after closing fragment or activity, this means your observable is still alive. For that you should unsubscribe your fragment in `onPause()` or `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`.  For example :

```
        Disposable disposable = callApiWithRetrofit().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(
        AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeWith(
        new DisposableObserver<List<YourPojo>>() {
            @Override
            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull List<AlertAssetDTO> listResponse) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onStop();
            disposable.dispose();
        }
```